# TKinter math output to canvas.create_text

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I am trying to calculate a formula and display its output as a table in TKinter.  Since it is not working, I am just trying to get a simple result and print it to a canvas widget.  When this gets working I will do the entire loan formula.  As it is I get no output in the GUI or in the console.
Is this even possible to place the result of a calculation as text in canvas.create_text?

```
from tkinter import * # Import tkinter

width = 500
height = 500

class MainGUI:
    def __init__(self):
        window = Tk() # Create a window
        window.title(" Loan Schedule ") # Set title

        frame1 = Frame(window)
        frame1.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

        Label(frame1, text = " Loan Amount ").grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W)
        self.v1 = StringVar()
        Entry(frame1, textvariable = self.v1, justify = RIGHT).grid(row = 1, column = 2)

        Label(frame1, text = " Years ").grid(row = 1, column = 3, sticky = W)
        self.v2 = StringVar()
        Entry(frame1, textvariable = self.v2, justify = RIGHT).grid(row = 1, column = 4)

        btCalculate = Button(frame1, text = " Calculate ", command = self.calculate()).grid(row = 1, column = 5, sticky = E)

        frame2 = Frame(window)
        frame2.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

        self.canvas = Canvas(frame2, width = width, height = height, bg = "white")
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.canvas.create_text(25, 25, text = self.calculate(), tags = "text")       

        window.mainloop() # Create an event loop

    def calculate(self):
        result = self.v1.get() + self.v2.get()
        print(result)
        return result

MainGUI()
```

Answer (score 0):

`command` require function name without ()

```
command = self.calculate
```

so now it works

```
from tkinter import * # Import tkinter

width = 500
height = 500

class MainGUI:
    def __init__(self):
        window = Tk() # Create a window
        window.title(" Loan Schedule ") # Set title

        frame1 = Frame(window)
        frame1.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

        Label(frame1, text = " Loan Amount ").grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W)
        self.v1 = StringVar()
        Entry(frame1, textvariable = self.v1, justify = RIGHT).grid(row = 1, column = 2)

        Label(frame1, text = " Years ").grid(row = 1, column = 3, sticky = W)
        self.v2 = StringVar()
        Entry(frame1, textvariable = self.v2, justify = RIGHT).grid(row = 1, column = 4)

        btCalculate = Button(frame1, text = " Calculate ", command = self.calculate).grid(row = 1, column = 5, sticky = E)

        frame2 = Frame(window)
        frame2.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

        self.canvas = Canvas(frame2, width = width, height = height, bg = "white")
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.canvas.create_text(55, 10, text = self.add_text(), tags = "text")       

        window.mainloop() # Create an event loop

    def calculate(self):
        result = int(self.v1.get()) + int(self.v2.get())
        self.canvas.create_text(25, 25, text = result, tags = "text")          
        print(result)
        return result

    def add_text(self):
        return "HELLO WORLD"

MainGUI()
```

by the way: line below means - run `self.calculate()` and result assign to `command`

```
command = self.calculate()
```

Comment: Aha, I see.  The meat that I was missing was the line self.canvas.create... in the calculate function that writes the result to the canvas.  That was what I missed or didn't remember that I could do.  Thanks for the tips, very helpful!